# Comparing date periods and date period lengths

Tags: java, jodatime

Suppose I have some bills with some start dates and end dates.

```
Mar 10 to Apr 9
Apr 10 to May 9
May 10 to Jun 9
```

The business rule that I want to check is that

`for any given bill, the previous bill is exactly one period behind`

So for example, Mar 10 to Apr 9 is about a month apart, and so I use that to check that any two consecutive bill start dates (Apr 10 vs Mar 10) are about a month apart.

Now the problem I'm having is obtaining the length of the period. For example, suppose I have the following data set

```
Jan 1 to Jan 31
Feb 1 to Feb 28
Mar 1 to Mar 31
```

I am using JodaTime library, so I say something like

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime date1 = formatter.parseDateTime("01/01/2013");
DateTime date2 = formatter.parseDateTime("31/01/2013");
System.out.println(Months.monthsBetween(date1, date2).toPeriod().getMonths());
```

And that returns 0, which is correct, but not useful.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime date1 = formatter.parseDateTime("31/01/2013");
DateTime date2 = formatter.parseDateTime("01/02/2013");
System.out.println(Months.monthsBetween(date1, date2).toPeriod().getMonths());
```

And that returns 1, even though it's a day apart.

What is a better way to do this? I can check days difference but since the billing periods are specified in months I would like any output to be consistent (eg: these bills are not x months apart, etc)

Comment: What about the condition that there is no day unbilled? What is `toPeriod()`?

Comment: @clwhisk sorry can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. For example, if one period was Jan 1 to Jan 25, and the next period was Feb 1 to Feb 25, and they are still "valid" because the missing days in between were not to be counted.

Comment: That's not what I meant - basically thought the same as dkatzel. The questions were about what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just check the the start date of one period minus one day is equal to the end date of the previous period?

```
LocalDate endDate1, startDate2...

startDate2.minusDays(1).equals(endDate1)
```

Comment: Oh, that would solve problem, assuming all bill periods are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

## `Interval`

If you switch to using specific moments (`DateTime` objects) rather than `LocalDate` objects, you can use the `Interval` class to track the span of time with the start and stop moments. A tip, if you go this way: [`DateTime::withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) method.

The [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class has handy comparison methods such as [`abuts`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#abuts-org.joda.time.ReadableInterval-), `gap`, `overlaps`, and `contains`. The first, `abuts`, is what you are looking for.

If you want to stick with `LocalDate` objects, you could build your own little `DateRange` class to behavior similarly to `Interval`. You might even find some example code here on Stack Overflow.

By the way, Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. The java.time classes are extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. That project offers an `Interval` class similar to the Joda-Time `Interval`.